# Apply Style based on property value

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Working with the Infragistics XamDataGrid I encountered a situation where I want a Style applied only if a certain property is set.  However, I think this is more of a general WPF/style question than xamDataGrid specific.

The below style is what I am currently using.  It adds checkBoxes to the record selector area:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:RecordSelector}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:RecordSelector}">
                <CheckBox x:Name="HeaderCheckBox"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataItem.IsChecked}">
                </CheckBox>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsFilterRecord" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="HeaderCheckBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                  </Trigger>
                  <Trigger Property="IsAddRecord" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="HeaderCheckBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                  </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The TargetType is RecordSelector.  If the record is either the filter row or the add record row, I don't want to show the check box.

I want to change this so that if the record is the add record row (IsAddRecord == true), then do not apply the style at all.  I want the add record row to retain its default style.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't prevent the Style from being aplied from within the Style itself, but you can prevent its Setters from being applied using Style.Triggers:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:RecordSelector}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsAddRecord" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igDP:RecordSelector}">
                        <CheckBox x:Name="HeaderCheckBox"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataItem.IsChecked}">
                        </CheckBox>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                          <Trigger Property="IsFilterRecord" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="HeaderCheckBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                          </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```